# Electric heat does not turn off when desired temperature reached

Tags: thermostat, baseboard, electric-heat

My electric heat (baseboards) do not turn off when the room reaches the desired temperature. It does turn off, however, when the thermostat setting itself switches (automatically if there's a schedule shift or manually).

I tried switching to a thermostat I know works fine and the problem is still there.

I have seen these already and they do not solve my problem:

- [Heater will not shut off when it reaches desired temperature](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/131171/heater-will-not-shut-off-when-it-reaches-desired-temperature)
- [Why won't my heater turn off when it reaches my desired temperature?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/4285/why-wont-my-heater-turn-off-when-it-reaches-my-desired-temperature)

Comment: are you buying the new one? did you contact the seller first?

Comment: No I took the new one from another room where it worked perfectly fine.

Comment: I would check the temperature at the thermostat with an separate thermometer. I've had some tstats that seemed to be really badly calibrated.

Answer (score 1):

On programmable units There is a dead band or span adjustment in your thermostat it is usually something like +1, -2 this means the call for heat will continue until 1 degree above the set point and it won’t restart until 2 degrees below the set point. This is normally a programmable feature.

For example I might program +2 , -0 for winter or heat mode and +0, -2 for cooling. Some thermostats come pre programmed +2, -2 this is larger than I like it cost a little more to have a tighter span but gets expensive at +-0 because the system is constantly starting and stopping.

Some electronic units don’t have a span control you just need to know there is a difference. On mechanical thermostats this was hysteresis or the mechanical lag it can be adjusted but may not be within 1 degree.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I believe something else is at play here, because the room becomes considerably hotter than the set point (more than 2 degrees). Do you have any other suggestions on what to look into? I'm stumped.

Comment: If the baseboards are not close to the thermostat not unusual. I live in the pacific northwest and baseboard and ceiling cable heat used to be the most common form of heat.  I can’t tell you how many times folks have had me install electronic thermostats thinking it would make a difference. With nothing to move the heat around and the heaters located away from the thermostats baseboard heat may have a significant difference. ceiling fans are the best advice I could give to move the air. The fans really do help move the air and create more uniform heat in the room. Actual TC probe measurement?

Comment: Alright I'll try throwing a fan in there and see if that does the trick! I'm also in the PNW, so your diagnosis sounds about right. I'll report back.